# image and file reference android

Tags: android, file-io

i'm making a hand-outs reader, i have an xml file contains the file link and the file thumbnail, i managed to parse the data inside the xml and save it in the sdcard. 
having a /mnt/sdcard/App/File directory for the downloaded files(.pdf, .ppt files) and /mnt/sdcard/App/Thumbnail for the downloaded thumbnails(.png, .jpeg/.jpg files)

i want to reference the image to the downloaded file (like when i click the image the file will show or open the referenced file) is it possible? if yes how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidFileSystem/article.html) tutorial should get you started on how to read/write from the SD card (if you don't already know how to do so), and [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-display-jpg-in-sdcard-on.html) tutorial should show you how to retrieve and display images stored on the SD card.